# file descriptor leak in java program : too many open files

Tags: java, file, memory-leaks, file-descriptor

I have a program which suffer from file descriptor increasing.
I see when I execute the command ls -l /proc/5969/fd where 5969 is the pid of the java program the number of file descriptor continuously increasing.
but I am unable to open one of those files decriptors to see what file remains open :
here is an example of the listing :

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 oct 24 16:08 52295 -> socket:[2577706264]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 oct 24 16:08 52296 -> socket:[2579543392]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 oct 24 16:08 52297 -> socket:[2578760962]
```

Please help me finding a way to solve this file descriptor leak in knowing what files remains open and increase the file descriptor number.

Answer (score 5):

Well, from a quick observation, you are using file descriptors on sockets, not files

In UNIX, both files and sockets use file descriptors, and so you have a problem where you are not closing sockets that you open.

As a result, you are not leaving a file open but are actually leaving port numbers locked from use by other programs.

Comment: It is not *just* the port numbers that he is tying down.  In UNIX / Linux, a process is only allowed to have a certain number of fd's (file descriptors) open, be they file fd's, socket fd's, pipe fd's or whatever.

Comment: I am not sure I am using socket and that I have port numbers locked.

Comment: do you know a way to see what are the open files remaining open to see where I let things open?

Comment: @zacky, you need to read my post. **There are no files open**. Whether you are using a 3rd party library or whether you are doing any network programming, the fact remains that based on what you posted, **there are no files open**.

Comment: ok but if you are telling me that the open files are sockets and not files so how can I see what socket url it is? I need to understand where my program is leaking

Comment: @zacky, research unix sockets. Please. They operate on ports, not URLs. You have everything you need to find the answer.

Comment: ok so a turnaround would be to have a command to close all open open sockets. is there a command in ubuntu for this?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
# lsof -p <pid>
```

will list all 'files' open by process id, may show you the ip/port the socket was bound to. If your program is client side, youre probably getting disconnected by TCP RST and not cleaning up the file descriptor properly.